Redundant Y-axis on plotly Box chart where color attribute is set
I tried to differentiate a single point in a "beeswarm" chart to see its location in a distribution. But setting color and color_discrete_map spreads out the dots; they seem to follow some values on the Y-axis.
player = "Lorenzo Lucca"

for i, stat in enumerate(stats, 1):
    fig = px.box(
            data_frame=info,
            x=stat,
            orientation="h",
            template="plotly_dark",
            height=250,
            width=800,
            hover_data={
                "Name": info.index,
                "Club": True,
                "Age": True, 
                "Mins": True,
                "Transfer Value": True,
                "Wage": True
            },
            color=info.index,
            color_discrete_map={
                player: 'red',
                **{name: '#636EFA' for name in info.index if name != player}
            },
            points="all"
    )
    
    fig.update_traces(
        boxpoints='all',
        pointpos=0,
        jitter=0.2,
        marker_size=8,
        fillcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        line={'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'},
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo='none',
        hoveron='points' 
    )
    
    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0),
        xaxis={'side': 'top'},
        showlegend=False,
        yaxis={
            'showticklabels': False, 
            'zeroline': False,
            'showgrid': False
        }
    )

    fig.show()

Desired alignment:

With color and color_discrete_map:


can you provide a sample of your data so we can reproduce the behavior you're seeing? copying and pasting the output from info.head().to_dict() int your question would be helpful
